# How to made zoom level configurable per node in drupal

Tags: drupal

I need to made map zoom level configurable for every node in drupal. I had tried various thing but it affects on either every view or every content type. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make map zoom level customization for every node you need to make some changes mentioned below:

http://w3solver.com/2016/08/30/how-to-customize-map-zoom-level-as-per-node-in-drupal/

It will guide you to do this.

create a view with lat, long and the title and  below is the js code that will help you to do this.

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
var locations = [
[‘Bondi Beach’, -33.890542, 151.274856],
[‘Coogee Beach’, -33.923036, 151.259052],
[‘Cronulla Beach’, -34.028249, 151.157507],
[‘Manly Beach’, -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
[‘Maroubra Beach’, -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]

// set title,lat., long value in this way.
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(‘map’), {
zoom: 15, // manage your zoom level here
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, ‘click’, (function(marker, i) {
marker.setIcon(‘path to your marker.’);
return function() {
infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
})(marker, i));
}
</script>
```

You can also show your own custom marker.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: To get title, lat,long  with view. alter the view file and put your code in the view template and set title name and lat,long dynamically. It will work. Hope it will help you.